# Partitioning multiline string in python

Tags: python, file, multilinestring

I'm running a unix command using python script, I'm storing its output (multi-line) in a string variable.
Now I have to make 3 files using that multi-line string by partitioning it into three parts (Delimited by a pattern ***End---End***).

This is what my Output variable contains

```
Output = """Text for file_A
something related to file_A
End---End
Text for file_B
something related to file_B
End---End
Text for file_C
something related to file_C
End---End"""
```

Now I want to have three files file_A, file_B and file_C for this value of Output:-

contents of ***file_A***

```
Text for file_A
something related to file_A
```

contents of ***file_B***

```
Text for file_B
something related to file_B
```

contents of ***file_C***

```
Text for file_C
something related to file_C
```

Also if Output doesn't have any text for its respective file then I don't want that file to be created.

E.g

```
Output = """End---End
Text for file_B
something related to file_B
End---End
Text for file_C
something related to file_C
End---End"""
```

Now I only want file_B and file_C to be created as there is no text for file_A

contents of ***file_B***

```
Text for file_B
something related to file_B
```

contents of ***file_C***

```
Text for file_C
something related to file_C
```

How can implement this in python? Is there any module to partition a multi-line string using some delimeter?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split()` method:

```
>>> pprint(Output.split('End---End'))
['Text for file_A\nsomething related to file_A\n',
 '\nText for file_B\nsomething related to file_B\n',
 '\nText for file_C\nsomething related to file_C\n',
 '']
```

Since there is a `'End---End'` at the end, the last split returns `''`, so you can specify the number of splits:

```
>>> pprint(Output.split('End---End',2))
['Text for file_A\nsomething related to file_A\n',
 '\nText for file_B\nsomething related to file_B\n',
 '\nText for file_C\nsomething related to file_C\nEnd---End']
```

Comment: upvoted the answer as it seems the question is a homework question so would hesitate to do more than hint.

Comment: thanks! duh!! I should really stop coming to this forum high :D This justifies my name 8-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Output = """Text for file_A
something related to file_A
End---End
Text for file_B
something related to file_B
End---End
Text for file_C
something related to file_C
End---End"""

ofiles = ('file_A', 'file_B', 'file_C')

def write_files(files, output):
    for f, contents in zip(files, output.split('End---End')):
        if contents:
            with open(f,'w') as fh:
                fh.write(contents)

write_files(ofiles, Output)
```